# Add UIViewController selector to Static Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, selector, uigesturerecognizer

I am creating a static library for Universal iOS app. The library takes the `UIViewController` of the caller viewcontroller as input and creates couple of subviews on that. Below is how the method is declared.

`-(void) initLibraryWithViewController:(UIViewController *)callerViewController;`

I have some buttons and images among these subviews. Now, I need to attach selectors for these subviews. I have added gestures to the images. I want the selectors of the gestures to be in the library itself so that the user of the library doesn't need to write anything regarding the library-generated controls at their end. I tried to attach selectors there but it throws error saying "**unrecognized selector sent to instance**". Below is how I added the target. I need to send the sender to the click event that's why I need the "**:**" in the selector. I tried with `[self libButtonClicked]` but that didn't work as well.

`[libButton addTarget:self action:@selector(libButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Is it possible to create selector of another viewcontroller to the library? Please help me with some examples. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the question. I fixed it. I was passing the caller viewcontroller instead of self as target. That was causing the error. Thanks for viewing.

Comment: hi Ranadhir ,i need full code i also have the same problem